# min-height: not working

Tags: javascript, html, styles

I have a fixed with container that has a simple structure like below. My problem is when I add children to the subContainer the subContainer will to give the illusion that it looses it's 100% height.

Events like this. Add first child every thing ok, and second child subContainer gives the impression that it is now 99% in height, and third child and subContainer seems to looks as if it is back to 100%;

The width always displays correctly. This one is driving me loco, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
 <div id="containerr" style="width: 175px; height: 250px;overflow:hidden;display: inline-block;">

  <div id="subContainer" style="width:100%; height:100%;">


    <div style="width:100%;height:25%;"></div> 
    <div style="width:100%;height:55%;"></div>
    <div style="width:100%;height:15%;"></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Which browser(s) and browser versions(s) is this behavior happening in?

Comment: This is happening in Google Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m

Comment: Does this help explain your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/Nf4rN/1/

Comment: Where's `min-height` in all this?

Comment: just a tip: are you using a properly DOCTYPE? as for example: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: This is the what my DOCTYPE? looks like.     <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

If you do the math, you'll notice that 25% of 250px is 62.5px and similarly for the other percentages. Based on what I'm seeing from

```
$('#subContainer > div:eq(0)').height()
```

it looks like FF is rounding up and Chrome is rounding down.  Some quick googling found that it is a known issue, eg. http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/